# Prove: If $(\exists V $ neighbourhood of $ x)(f_{\mid V}:V\to Y$ is continous) then $f$ is continous in $x$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: (X,\tau_X) \to (Y,\tau_Y), x\in X$ and $v\subseteq X$;
>
> Prove: If $(\exists V $ neighbourhood of $ x)(f_{\mid V}:V\to Y$ is continous <s>in $x$</s>) then $f$ is continous in $x$.

I get kinda stuck in the following proof, could someone give a hint?

#### Proof:

Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $f(x)$, I want to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. This is true if $(\exists \tilde{W} \in \tau_X)(x\in \tilde{W} \subseteq f^{-1}(U))$. In the proof I will be looking for such a $\tilde{W}$.

Consider the $U$ above as a neighbourhood of $f_{\mid V} = f(x)$. Since $f_{\mid V}$ is continous $f^{-1}_{\mid V}(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

Hence $(\exists W\in \tau_\color{red}{V})(x\in W\subseteq f^{-1}_{\mid V} (U))$.

I can't use this $W$ as $\tilde W$ since the above implies

$$x\in A\cap V\subseteq f^{-1}(U)\cap V \qquad \text{where}\quad A\in \tau_X$$
Which does not result in $x\in A\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ as denoted in the picture. I think the biggest problem lies in the fact I'm using the relative topology $\tau_\color{red}{V}$, but how can I resolve this?
[image: visual]

#### edit:

I just noticed the theorem states $f_{\mid V}:V\to Y$ is continous (instead of continous at $x$)

Comment: You haven't used so far that $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thanks, that gets me further. Let $(B\in \tau_X)(x\in B\subseteq V)$ then I could consider $\tilde W = A\cap B$, where $x\in \tilde{W}\in \tau_X$. But I don't think it is assured that $\tilde W \in f^{-1}(U)$, is it?

Comment: $f^{-1}(U)\cap V=f|_V^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ relative to $V$, that's why it is equal to $N\cap V$ for some neighborhood $N$ of $x$ in $X$ (take $N=A\cup(f^{-1}(U)\cap V)$ for example). Since the intersection of neighborhoods of $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$, you can take $\tilde W=N\cap V$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $x$ and let $V$ be the neighbourhood described above.

Let $N$ be a neighbourhood of $f(x)$ and let $M \subset V$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ such that $f_{\mid V}(M) \subset N $. Since $f(y) = f_{\mid V}(y)$ for all $y \in V$, we see that $f(M) \subset N $, and so $f$ is continuous at $x$.